# Using 'w' and 'r' in txt files

Tags: python

## How can I use the 'r' and 'w' at the same time?

### Hi I want to know if I can use 'r' and 'w' at the same time, the following is an example

```
# Example
with open('txt.txt', 'w') as t:
    t.write('Hello World')
    t.readable()
    eg = t.readlines()
```

> When I write this down it will create the txt file but it gives me an error.
> I Want to know how to use 'r' and 'w' at the same time

- Please help me
- I am suffering
- I need help

Comment: to add to the file and not delete:
`f=open("guru99.txt", "a")`
to read and write:
`f=open("guru99.txt", "r+")`
to write:
`f=open("guru99.txt", "w+")`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You use `r+`. The `r` character means read-only, `w` means write-only, `r+` means read *and* write.

Just keep in mind that you'll probably need to manage the file pointers (where your current position is) when switching between read and write operations.